# IntelliJ Scala so slow on fast CPU with 32GB ram

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 2019.1.3 Community Edition.
In Scala compile server, `JVM maximum heap size: 4096`
my idea.vmoptions:

```
-Xms4096m
-Xmx6144m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2048m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Xverify:none

-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea.hprof
```

**Environment**

- IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Community Edition) Build #IC-191.7479.19, built on May 28, 2019 JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b58 x86_64 JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o macOS 10.14.5
- IntelliJ Scala plugin v2019.1.8
- CPU: 2,6 GHz Intel Core i7
- 32 GB 2400 MHz DDR4

memory indicator shows `2582 used of 6060M`

my current project is quite big, ( over 800 files )
and very often even in small files intellij can hang for a few secs, inpections took ages..
Can I speed it up ?

Comment: I have the memory indicator switched on, so I see if IDEA doesn't have enough memory.
Preferences / Appearance & Behavior / Appearance / Show memory indicator

Comment: edited post, used not even half of memory

Comment: Maybe you can exclude parts of your project by right clicking on a file or directory and choosing "Mark as / Excluded".

Comment: @bmateusz I would better like to use everything :) and use machine as hard as possible.

Comment: I had the same problem in a big project, which version of intelliJ are you using ? And which version of Scala plug-in ? I partially solved updating IntelliJ and Scala plugin

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL with the logs and the CPU snapshot attached: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085, https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235.

Comment: @DavidGeirola Intellij version: IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.7479.19, built on May 28, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b58 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14.5

Comment: and scala plugin v2019.1.8

Comment: @CrazyCoder ok thank I will do this today

Comment: @Baku i've updated the question adding your environment information

Answer (score 0):

If this still occurs, you should file a bug; as a user of IntelliJ you should not need to worry about a slow editor.

To investigate the problem further, you can first look in the directory from "Help | Show Log in $FileManager". If there are any subdirectories named `threadDumps-*`, you can find out what stops the editor from being responsive.

You can find more details in the [instructions for reporting performance problems in IDEA](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems).